# Canvas game slows down after a while. What could have caused this?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm making a breakout game with html canvas and javascript. I'm working on this project for a while.
Yesterday i realized that game started the slow down after hours of playing. I checked my code but everything was fine. Then i restarted chrome and the game back to normal. What could have caused this?
Is chrome collecting objects or something on the background and it gets heavy after hours? is that a thing?
Here is the all the js code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
canvas = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp, false);
document.querySelector("#newGame").addEventListener("click", newGame, false);
document.querySelector("#pickLevel").addEventListener("click", pickLevel, false);
document.querySelector("#restart").addEventListener("click", restart, false);
document.querySelector("#toMainMenu").addEventListener("click", mainMenu, false);


levels = {

    map01 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 8, 10, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 13, 15, 17, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 14, 20, 2, 4, 17, 8, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 2, 9, 11, 9, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 10, 11, 18, 16, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 11, 3, 0, 0, 19, 20, 0, 0, 3, 11, 3, 0, 2, 10, 18, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 10, 18, 10, 1, 0, 17, 13, 17, 9, 1, 0, 0, 1, 9, 17, 5, 17, 0, 0, 0, 20, 12, 16, 8, 7, 6, 8, 3, 4, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 11, 15, 14, 13, 15, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 10, 21, 20, 2, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 9, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map02 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 17, 18, 19, 4, 5, 0, 0, 8, 11, 14, 10, 13, 0, 0, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 0, 15, 18, 21, 17, 20, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, 0, 21, 14, 7, 6, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 0, 0, 7, 20, 7, 13, 14, 0, 0, 9, 12, 8, 11, 14, 0, 0, 14, 6, 12, 4, 10, 0, 0, 16, 19, 15, 18, 21, 0, 0, 21, 13, 19, 11, 17, 0, 0, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 0, 8, 20, 15, 18, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 13, 14, 5, 1, 0, 0, 7, 9, 13, 14, 14, 0, 0, 10, 13, 9, 12, 8, 0, 0, 14, 6, 12, 4, 10, 0, 0, 17, 20, 16, 19, 15, 0, 0, 21, 13, 19, 11, 17, 0, 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 0, 15, 20, 11, 18, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map03 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map04 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 3, 11, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 17, 16, 18, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 10, 17, 18, 19, 13, 14, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 4, 19, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 10, 17, 7, 0, 6, 1, 16, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 6, 7, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map05 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 15, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 16, 0, 0, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 17, 0, 13, 7, 0, 10, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 18, 0, 5, 20, 14, 6, 0, 11, 5, 0, 0, 0, 13, 19, 0, 4, 12, 20, 21, 13, 20, 0, 12, 6, 0, 14, 20, 0, 3, 11, 19, 0, 0, 20, 12, 4, 0, 13, 7, 21, 0, 2, 10, 18, 0, 3, 4, 0, 19, 11, 3, 0, 14, 0, 1, 9, 17, 0, 7, 10, 11, 1, 0, 18, 10, 2, 0, 7, 8, 16, 0, 10, 14, 17, 18, 8, 7, 0, 17, 9, 1, 14, 15, 0, 1, 17, 21, 0, 0, 15, 14, 3, 0, 16, 8, 0, 0, 1, 8, 19, 0, 17, 18, 0, 21, 10, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 15, 0, 2, 8, 9, 10, 0, 17, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 11, 0, 0, 14, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map06 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 1, 8, 16, 11, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 8, 15, 4, 0, 13, 6, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 3, 9, 15, 19, 0, 20, 5, 13, 21, 0, 0, 0, 17, 4, 10, 16, 12, 0, 7, 4, 12, 20, 19, 0, 0, 2, 5, 11, 17, 5, 0, 21, 3, 11, 19, 12, 0, 0, 9, 6, 12, 18, 20, 0, 1, 2, 10, 18, 18, 0, 0, 16, 17, 13, 19, 13, 0, 8, 1, 9, 17, 11, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15, 20, 6, 0, 2, 7, 8, 16, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 17, 21, 0, 9, 6, 14, 15, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 14, 0, 16, 5, 13, 21, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 4, 4, 12, 20, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 3, 11, 19, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 10, 10, 18, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 15, 17, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 17, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map07 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 20, 0, 0, 0, 20, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 13, 18, 14, 0, 8, 2, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 2, 5, 21, 3, 15, 3, 4, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 19, 9, 12, 7, 10, 6, 10, 11, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 10, 21, 16, 19, 14, 17, 13, 17, 18, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0, 17, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 8, 9, 2, 0, 0, 0, 11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 15, 16, 9, 0, 0, 0, 18, 20, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 7, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 16, 17, 18, 19, 16, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 6, 7, 5, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 14, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20, 20, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map08 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 19, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 6, 16, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 13, 3, 19, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 20, 10, 6, 15, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 7, 17, 13, 2, 17, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 14, 4, 20, 9, 4, 19, 13, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 11, 7, 16, 11, 8, 20, 14, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 8, 18, 14, 17, 18, 15, 16, 21, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 18, 15, 18, 21, 19, 20, 21, 8, 9, 10, 11, 10, 0, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    map09 : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 7, 0, 3, 6, 17, 18, 11, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 8, 0, 14, 0, 10, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 15, 0, 21, 0, 17, 20, 20, 21, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 10, 2, 0, 6, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 17, 9, 0, 13, 0, 9, 12, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 13, 0, 1, 16, 0, 20, 0, 16, 19, 0, 0, 9, 10, 0, 20, 0, 4, 3, 0, 5, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 16, 17, 0, 7, 0, 11, 10, 0, 12, 0, 8, 11, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 14, 0, 18, 17, 0, 19, 0, 15, 18, 0, 0, 8, 4, 0, 21, 0, 5, 4, 0, 4, 0, 7, 3, 0, 0, 15, 11, 0, 1, 0, 12, 11, 0, 11, 0, 14, 10, 0, 0, 2, 18, 0, 8, 0, 19, 18, 0, 18, 0, 21, 17, 0, 0, 9, 5, 0, 15, 0, 6, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 12, 0, 2, 0, 13, 12, 0, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 0, 9, 0, 20, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9, 0, 16, 0, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 15, 16, 17, 0, 18, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

};

let map_col = 14;
let map_row = 34;

let secondPassed = 0;
let oldTimeStamp = 0;

let WIDTH = canvas.canvas.width;
let HEIGHT = canvas.canvas.height;

let right_arrow_keycode = 39;
let left_arrow_keycode = 37;
let a_keycode = 65;
let d_keycode = 68;

let pressLeft;
let pressRight;
let game_over;
let islevelUp;

let dt = 1/60.0;

let brickList;

let tilesets = {
    tileset1: {
        image: new Image(),
        columns: 7,
        rows: 3,
        tile_width: 32,
        tile_height: 16
    }
};
tilesets.tileset1.image.src = "img/tileset/brick_tileset.png";

let heart_sprite_sheet = {
    spin: {
        frame_set : [0,1,2,3],
        image : new Image() 
    }
}
heart_sprite_sheet.spin.image.src = "img/heart/heart_sprite.png";

let delay = 0;
let frame_set;
let level;


function newGame(){
    document.querySelector(".mainMenu").style.display="none";
    level = 0;
    score = 0;
    levelUp();
}
function restart(){
    document.querySelector(".gameOver").style.display="none";
    level -= 1;
    levelUp();
}
function mainMenu(){
    document.querySelector(".gameOver").style.display="none";
    document.querySelector(".mainMenu").style.display="block";
}
function pickLevel(){
    score = 0;
    document.querySelector(".pickLevel").style.display="block";
    document.querySelector(".mainMenu").style.display="none";
}
function loop(timeStamp){
    getDeltaTime(timeStamp);

    ballCollision();

    ballMovement();
    paddleMovement();
    heartMovement();

    heartAnimUpdate();
    // document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "gameover: " + game_over + ", islevelup: " + islevelUp;
    
    draw();

    if(!game_over && !islevelUp){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }
    else if(game_over){
        gameOver();
    }
    else if(islevelUp){
        levelUp();
    }

}
function Animation(){
    this.count = 0
    this.delay = delay;
    this.frame = 0;
    this.frame_index = 0;
    this.frame_set = frame_set;
}
Animation.prototype.change = function(frame_set, delay){
    if(this.frame_set != frame_set){
        this.count = 0;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.frame_index = 0;
        this.frame_set = frame_set;
        this.frame = this.frame_set[this.frame_index];
    }
}
Animation.prototype.update = function(){        
    this.count ++;
        if(this.count >= this.delay){
            this.count = 0;
            this.frame_index =(this.frame_index == this.frame_set.length -1)?0: this.frame_index + 1;
            this.frame = this.frame_set[this.frame_index];
        }
}
function Ball(){
    this.image = new Image(),
    this.x = 250,
    this.y = 450,
    this.velocity = 150,
    this.radius = 8,
    this.dx = 1,
    this.dy = -1
}
function ballReset(){
    ball.x = paddle.x + paddle.width/2;
    ball.y = 450;
    ball.dx = 1;
    ball.dy = -1;
    ball.velocity = 150;
}
function drawBall(){
    canvas.drawImage(ball.image, Math.floor(ball.x), Math.floor(ball.y), ball.radius*2, ball.radius*2);
}
function ballMovement(){
    ball.x += (ball.velocity * deltaTime ) * ball.dx * 0.999;
    ball.y += (ball.velocity * deltaTime ) * ball.dy * 0.999;
}
function ballCollision(){
    //borders for ball
    if(ball.y - ball.radius <= 0 && ball.y < 0){
        ball.dy = ball.dy * -1;
        ball.y = ball.radius;
    }
    if(ball.y > HEIGHT){
        heartList.pop();
        if(heartList.length == 0){
            game_over = true;
        }else{
            ballReset();
        }

    }
    if(ball.x + ball.radius > WIDTH && ball.x > 0){
        ball.dx = ball.dx * -1;
        ball.x = WIDTH-ball.radius;
    }
    if(ball.x - ball.radius < 0 && ball.x < 0){
        ball.dx = ball.dx * -1;
        ball.x = ball.radius;
    }

    // ball and paddle collision detection
    let testX = ball.x;
    let testY = ball.y;

    if(ball.x < paddle.x){
        testX = paddle.x;
        //left
    }
    else if(ball.x > paddle.x+paddle.width){
        testX = paddle.x + paddle.width;
        //right
    }
    if(ball.y < paddle.y){
        testY = paddle.y;
        //top
    }
    else if(ball.y > paddle.y+ paddle.height){
        testY = paddle.y + paddle.height;
        //bottom
    }

    let distX = ball.x - testX;
    let distY = ball.y - testY;

    let distance = Math.sqrt((distX*distX)+(distY*distY));

    if(distance <= ball.radius){
        let collidePoint = ball.x - (paddle.x + paddle.width/2);
        collidePoint = collidePoint / (paddle.width/2);

        let angle = collidePoint * Math.atan2(ball.y, ball.x);
        ball.dx = ball.velocity * deltaTime  * Math.sin(angle);
        ball.dy = -ball.velocity * deltaTime * Math.cos(angle);
    }
    
    //brick collision
    
    for (let i = 0; i < brickList.length; i++){
        let b = brickList[i];
        if(b.status){
            let bottom = false;
            let top = false;
            let b_testX = ball.x;
            let b_testY = ball.y;

            if(ball.x < b.x){
                b_testX = b.x;
            }
            else if(ball.x > b.x + b.width){
                b_testX = b.x + b.width;
            }
            if(ball.y < b.y){
                b_testY = b.y;
                top = true;
            }
            else if(ball.y > b.y + b.height){
                b_testY = b.y + b.height;
                bottom = true;
                
            }

            let distX_fromBrick = ball.x - b_testX;
            let distY_fromBrick = ball.y - b_testY;

            let distance = Math.sqrt((distX_fromBrick * distX_fromBrick) + (distY_fromBrick * distY_fromBrick));

            if(distance < ball.radius){
                let collidePoint = ball.x - (b.x + b.width/2);
                collidePoint = collidePoint / (b.width/2);

                let angle = collidePoint * Math.atan2(ball.y, ball.x);
                if(top){
                    ball.dx = ball.velocity * deltaTime * Math.sin(angle);
                    ball.dy = -ball.velocity * deltaTime * Math.cos(angle);
                }
                if(bottom){
                    ball.dx = -ball.velocity * deltaTime * Math.sin(angle);
                    ball.dy = ball.velocity * deltaTime * Math.cos(angle);
                }
                b.status = false;
                brokenBricks ++;
                scoreUp();
                if(brokenBricks == brickList.length){
                    islevelUp = true;
                }
            }


        }
            
    }
}
function Paddle(){
    this.image = new Image(),
    this.x = 200,
    this.y = 490,
    this.width = 64,
    this.height = 20,
    this.velocity = 500
}   
function drawPaddle(){
    canvas.drawImage(paddle.image, Math.floor(paddle.x), Math.floor(paddle.y),paddle.width,paddle.height);
}
function paddleMovement(){
    if(pressRight&&paddle.x+paddle.width<WIDTH){
        paddle.x += (paddle.velocity * deltaTime  )*0.999;
    }
    if(pressLeft&&paddle.x>0){
        paddle.x -= (paddle.velocity * deltaTime )*0.999;
    }
}
function Brick(x,y){
    this.image = new Image(),
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.width = 32,
    this.height = 16,
    this.status = true
}
function drawMap (){
    for(let i = 0; i < map.length; i++){
        let value = map[i]-1;
        
        let source_x = (value%tilesets.tileset1.columns) * tilesets.tileset1.tile_width;
        let source_y = Math.floor(value/tilesets.tileset1.columns) * tilesets.tileset1.tile_height;

        let destination_x = (i%map_col) * tilesets.tileset1.tile_width;
        let destination_y = Math.floor(i/map_col) * tilesets.tileset1.tile_height;
        if(map[i] != 0){
            if(!isBrickAlive(destination_x, destination_y)){continue;}
        }
        canvas.drawImage(tilesets.tileset1.image, source_x, source_y, tilesets.tileset1.tile_width, tilesets.tileset1.tile_height, destination_x, destination_y, tilesets.tileset1.tile_width, tilesets.tileset1.tile_height );

    }
}
function createBrick(){
    for(let i = 0; i<map.length; i++){
        if(map[i] != 0){
            let x = (i%map_col)*tilesets.tileset1.tile_width;
            let y = Math.floor(i/map_col)*tilesets.tileset1.tile_height;
            let brick = new Brick(x, y);
            brickList.push(brick);
        }   
    }
}
function isBrickAlive(x,y){
    for(let i = 0; i < brickList.length; i++){
        let brick = brickList[i];
        if(brick.status && brick.x == x && brick.y == y){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
function scoreUp(){
    score += 1;
}
function scoreText(){
    canvas.font = `15px gameFont`;
    canvas.fillStyle = "white";
    canvas.fillText("SCORE:"+ score, 8, 30);
}
function Heart(x,y){
    this.image = new Image(),
    this.animation = new Animation(),
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.width = 7,
    this.height = 7
}
function heartCreate(){
    let heart1 = new Heart(350,8);
    heartList.push(heart1);
    let heart2 = new Heart(375,8);
    heartList.push(heart2);
    let heart3 = new Heart(400,8);
    heartList.push(heart3);
    let heart4 = new Heart(425,8);
    heartList.push(heart4);
}
function heartDraw(){
    for(let i = 0; i < heartList.length; i++){
        let heart = heartList[i];
        canvas.drawImage(heart_sprite_sheet.spin.image, heart.width * heart.animation.frame, 0, heart.width, heart.height, heart.x, heart.y, heart.width*3, heart.height*3);
    }
}
function heartMovement(){
    for(let i = 0; i < heartList.length; i++){
        let heart = heartList[i];
        heart.image = heart_sprite_sheet.spin.image;
        heart.animation.change(heart_sprite_sheet.spin.frame_set, 12);
    }
}
function heartAnimUpdate(){
    for(let i = 0; i < heartList.length; i++){
        let heart = heartList[i];
        heart.animation.update();
    }
}
function draw(){
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    canvas.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    canvas.save();
    drawBg();
    drawMap();
    drawPaddle();
    scoreText();
    heartDraw();
    drawBall();
    canvas.restore();
    
}
function keyDown(event){
    if(event.keyCode === right_arrow_keycode || event.keyCode === d_keycode){
        pressRight = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode === left_arrow_keycode || event.keyCode === a_keycode){
        pressLeft = true;
    }
}
function keyUp(event){
    if(event.keyCode === right_arrow_keycode || event.keyCode === d_keycode){
        pressRight = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode === left_arrow_keycode || event.keyCode === a_keycode){
        pressLeft = false;
    }
}
function drawBg(){
    switch(level){
        case 1:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#76428A";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 2:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#8C2929";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 3:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#639BFF";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 4:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#4B692F";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 5:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#9BADB7";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 6:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#D95763";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 7:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#3F3F74";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 8:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#663931";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        case 9:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#DF7126";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
        default:
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.fillStyle =  "#639BFF";
            canvas.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            canvas.closePath();
            break;
    }
    //açık mavi: 639BFF
    //mor: 76428A
    //yeşil: 4B692F
    //pembe: D77BBA
    //turuncu: DF7126
    //koyu mavi: 3F3F74
    //pembe-kırmızı: D95763
    //koyu mor: 45283C
    //baby-blue: 9BADB7
    //mavi: 5B6EE1
    //koyu kırmızı: 8C2929
}
function getDeltaTime(timeStamp){
    secondPassed = (timeStamp - oldTimeStamp) / 1000;
    oldTimeStamp = timeStamp;
    deltaTime = Math.min(secondPassed , dt);
    return deltaTime;
}
function startGame(){
    secondPassed = 0;
    oldTimeStamp = 0;

    brokenBricks = 0;
    
    game_over = false;
    pressLeft = false;
    pressRight = false;
    islevelUp = false;
    
    
    brickList = new Array();
    heartList = new Array();

    createBrick();
    heartCreate();
    
    draw();

    startEngine();
}
function startEngine(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
function gameOver(){
    document.querySelector(".gameOver").style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score;
    score = 0;
}
function levelUp(){
    ball = new Ball();
    paddle = new Paddle();

    level++;
    switch(level){
        case 1:
            map = levels.map01;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/blue_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/black_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 2:
            map = levels.map02;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/green_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/blue_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 3:
            map = levels.map03;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/purple_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/brown_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 4:
            map = levels.map04;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/red_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/golden_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 5:
            map = levels.map05;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/yellow_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/green_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 6:
            map = levels.map06;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/blue_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/purple_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 7:
            map = levels.map07;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/red_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/red_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 8:
            map = levels.map08;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/yellow_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/black_paddle.png";
            break;
        case 9:
            map = levels.map09;
            ball.image.src = "img/ball/purple_ball.png";
            paddle.image.src = "img/paddle/blue_paddle.png";
            break;
        default:
            game_over = true;
            break;
    }
    startGame();
}});
```

Comment: I mean without any code it's really difficult to answer this question. It could be any number of things and as it stands no one can reliably answer this question

Comment: should i add all my code? because i don't know which part causing it.

Comment: My only guess would be you're not cleaning up old entities/blocks so you end up with massive amounts of sprites still (even if not displayed on screen). Are you using a library or is it all your own code? Do you have anything that lists all the current active entities/sprites? That would be my first port of call. Display a count of how many sprites you have and increase/decrease as you add and remove. Then you can see if you aren't cleaning things up properly

Comment: no i don't use any framework its just pure javascript and i added my code can you check it out? i think brick objects can cause it

Comment: Looks like a memory leak. You can check the memory usage over https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems

Comment: Thank you! Yes it seems like memory leak according the article. I tried to detected the leak and i think the problem is drawing the map, so i added a buffer canvas for that reason. It looks like its working fine for now.